# Cartesian product with restrictions

Tags: c#

Hello, I am new in C# Programming and I would like to ask a question related to the cartesian product. I found the method for calculating through StackOverflow and I used it. The method I use is:

```
char[] letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };

int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

string[] colours = { "Red", "Blue" };


var cartesianProduct = from letter in letters
                       from number in numbers
                       from colour in colours
                       select new { letter, number, colour };
```

In my case the cartesian product means something. For example for the combination "A1Red" I upload to the program an array with the consistency values between A and 1 and A and Red. What I need from the program is to give me the sum of this values.

It works perfectly if i have 10 arrays to find the combinations but it stuck when I need to calculate over 23 arrays and total amount of combinations more than 100 trillions.

Is there something that I can do to make it run fast?

Comment: What do you actually want? What's with the consistency values? What do they mean? How are they stored? Do you want one number in the end or do you really want all combinations?

Comment: What do you intend to use these 100 trillions values for?

Comment: The sum of the consistancy values helps me to distinguish which of the combinations are useful.I upload a matrix in a datagridview and i store it to an array! after that i use the array in if else conditions to find the sum of the combinations. The point is to take the first 10.000 combinations from the 100 trillion ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not much you can do. Your problem requires so-called "exponential time".

As @esel points out, you can do *some* optimizations, and you can use parallellism.
But unless there is an underlying structure to your arrays, something correlation between the data that you can exploit, you're simply stuck with this "exponential time". Every array added to your list, will multiply the amount of time needed to compute. This escalates fast.

There is a very small consolation: as soon as any of your arrays is empty, this flattens the whole thing to the empty set.

See if there is an underlying structure to your data that you can exploit.

**Edit:** 
In the comments, you mention taking the first 10.000 combinations. I'm not quite sure I understand the rest, but if you need the first 10.000 of `cartesianProduct` (i.e. unprocessed), then there is a way:

```
var first10000 = cartesianProduct.Take(10000);
```

This works because LinQ uses "lazy evaluation": it will not calculate the values in the cartesian product until it has to. As a consequence, no more than 10000 values will be calculated.
However, if some processing needs to be done first, like sorting, then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Is there a way based on what you answered to make it give me one part each time, for example from 0 to 10000 and then from 10001 to 20000? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could combine `Take` and [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . But keep in mind - if you want to look at the entire cartesian product, you're simply stuck with that exponential time. Processing it in chunks of 10000 elements won't solve that deeper problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to make some algorithms run more quickly, using parallelism to process multiple parts of the domain at once by taking advantage of many cores and special CPU or GPU instructions.

However, there are temporal limits. If the answer space is indeed that large, you simply cannot compute the results in a reasonable amount time.